# How come javascript is recognizing that my control is now holding an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm working on small `MVC` application that is "sending emails", and at the begining I used dropdown to choose only 1 receiver, but after that I added multiple class to my dropdownList and when I choose 2-3 receivers and when I tried to debug this code which I used with only one receiver :

```
$("#SubmitEmail").click(function () {
    var Receiver = $('#ReceiverID').val();
    var Subject = $('#subject').val();
    var Body = $('#content').val();
    var obj = { 'Receiver': Receiver, 'Subject': Subject, 'Body': Body };

    SendEmail(obj);
});
```

I realized that `var Receiver` which I used to store receiverId, become an array acctually, and I'm wondering how come javascript adapted soo cooooool so it recognized that I've selected few items there, and it become an array so I simply looped it (modified my code):

```
$("#SubmitEmail").click(function () {
    var Receivers = $('#ReceiverID').val();
    for (var i = 0; i < Receivers.length; i++) {
        var Receiver = Receivers[i];
        var Subject = $('#subject').val();
        var Body = $('#content').val();
        var obj = { 'Receiver': Receiver, 'Subject': Subject, 'Body': Body };
    }
    SendEmail(obj);
});
```

And everything was cooool, so I'm simply wondering how come js knows it all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery docs on val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1):

> When the first element in the collection is a select-multiple (i.e., a
>   **select** element with the **multiple** attribute set), .val() returns an
>   **array** containing the value of each selected option.

So it's actually jQuery magic, not JavaScript magic.

You can see the actual source code for `val()` [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/56136897f241db22560b58c3518578ca1453d5c7/src/attributes/val.js#L15). It's a function that calls the [`get` hook](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/56136897f241db22560b58c3518578ca1453d5c7/src/attributes/val.js#L100) of the `select` element, which actually does a loop over the selected options.

Comment: so when there is no more than a one element than it is not returning an array, than element itself?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro No, it returns an array with just one element. See for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/pyko71fz/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is cool as you state, but in this example it, in fact, is a Jquery implementation flexibility which returns array of objects for dropdown. see http://api.jquery.com/val/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

This is how jQuery works. See .val() function:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Scroll down for this example:

Get the single value from a single select and an array of values from a multiple select and display their values.